# How to compare a char pointer with a string

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

Right now I need to create an `if` statement that can compare a char pointer with a string like the following statement:

```
if (Start == "on"){
    Serial.println("virker");
}
```

The problem is that this simple sentence does not work. The variable `Start` is a string containing the word on that I get from a web page that sends a JSON object via a AJAX request. The object looks like this when I receive it:

```js
{"start":"on","relay":"off","computer_alert":"off","esp_alert":"off","alarm1":{"tilstand":"off","tid":"null"},"alarm2":{"tilstand":"off","tid":"null"},"alarm3":{"tilstand":"off","tid":"null"}}
```

I've tried to give `Start` a value inside the program and that works. My entire code can be seen below:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Hash.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid     = "ESP8266-Access-Point";
const char* password = "123456789";
const int buzzer = 0;
const int relay = 6;
const char* Start;
int d;
const char* test = "on";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "Json";

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void ekstern() {
    const int buzzer = 0;
    const int relay = 6;
    pinMode(relay and buzzer, OUTPUT);
}


void setup() {
    ESP.eraseConfig();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

    IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
    Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
    Serial.println(IP);

    if(!SPIFFS.begin()){
        Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
        return;
    }
    server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
        request->send(SPIFFS, "/HTML.html");
    });
    server.on("/JQ", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
       request->send(SPIFFS, "/JQ.js");
    });
    server.on("/CSS", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
        request->send(SPIFFS, "/CSS.css");
    });
    server.on("/GET", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        String json;
        if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)) {
            json = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
            Serial.println(json);
        }
        request->send(200, "text/plain", "OK");

        StaticJsonDocument<384> doc;

        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json);

        if (error) {
            Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
            Serial.println(error.f_str());
            return;
        }

        Start = doc["start"]; // "off"
        const char* relay = doc["relay"]; // "off"
        const char* computer_alert = doc["computer_alert"]; // "off"
        const char* esp_alert = doc["esp_alert"]; // "off"
    
        const char* alarm1_tilstand = doc["alarm1"]["tilstand"]; // "off"
        long alarm1_tid = doc["alarm1"]["tid"]; // 3184358
    
        const char* alarm2_tilstand = doc["alarm2"]["tilstand"]; // "off"
        long alarm2_tid = doc["alarm2"]["tid"]; // 3184358
    
        const char* alarm3_tilstand = doc["alarm3"]["tilstand"]; // "off"
        long alarm3_tid = doc["alarm3"]["tid"]; // 3244358
        Serial.println(alarm3_tid);
        Serial.println(alarm3_tilstand);
    });
  
    server.begin();
}
void loop(){
    if (Start == "on"){
        Serial.println("virker");
    }
    Serial.println(Start);
    Serial.println("hallo");
    delay(5000);
}
```

I don't think it makes any difference, but I am using the ESP8266.

Comment: [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/ https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/use-string-view-on-esp32/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value in the pointer to a String by useing the following command,

```
String();
```

For me it did not work when i used the following command,

```
strcmp();
```

The command just gave a exception (28) error. I feel a little bit stupid because i am pretty sure i used the String() before and it didnt work, but i must have done something else wrong because it wroks now. The solution was to write the if statement like this,

```
if(String(Start)=="on"){
Serial.println("virker");
```

}

UPD: The methode I described above does work, but stackoverflow user dpronin made me aware that the methode has some problems. The problem came from when the program received the JSON object because just saving the pointer made the program buggy. The solution was useing this command,

```
strncpy();
```

Which copies the string to another variable instead of just pointing to the memory addresse. When I changed to this methode my code worked. I will also say that it may be the reason why the following command didnt work,

```
strcmp();
```

I have tested it again after the changes.

Comment: How did you use `strcmp`? The correct usage would be something like `strcmp(a, b) == 0`. Is that what you did?

Comment: `String` is a C++ class in the Arduino library. A *string literal* like `"on"` is not a `String`, it is a *C-style string*. A `char*` value can also represent a C-style string. You compare C-style strings with `strcmp`. You can also convert one ot both of the C-style string operands to `String` and use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `doc` is a stack variable that will vanish as just you leave the request handler `GET`. This means that you will absolutely definitely access to already dangling pointer, which `Start` variable stores, in `loop` function because it points to the already not existing `doc["start"]`. You **have to** preserve data from `doc["start"]` rather than the pointer `doc["start"]` contains. For that you need to define `Start` as an array of chars and then use `strncpy` to copy characters from the `doc["start"]` into `Start` variable. Further, in `loop` function you need to use `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare "on" with characters in the variable `Start`. As easy as it gets

UPD: Also GET request MUST NOT change the state of your server conventionally, therefore `Start` variable is not supposed to be altered

Comment: `doc` is inside the request handler.

Comment: @gre_gor, I updated, thank you, this was my fault. Nevertheless, does it change anything? It is still a stack variable